# backbone collection url does not take parameters

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a `Backbone Collection` class with the `url` property set to a method.

The `url` is comprised of 3 "elements" which I have called `baseUrl`, `username` and `path` - so it would look something like `baseUrl/username/path`

I use the same instance for several users in the spa I am working on. However the one element I want to be able to change (after instantiation) is the username. I need this for 2 reasons.

1st - I don't have the username property at instantiation time.

2nd - The username changes depending on the user and I don't want to create new instances of the collection for every new user.

So my issue is why does the `url` method not take parameters after instantiating the collection so that I could do something like `myCollection.url({username: "Mac"})`?

Also why does `Backbone` not allow for parameters to be passed into the `url` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone calls the [`url`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url) method with the collection as the context, so you can access member variables of your collection instance with `this`.

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: function() {
        return "base-url/" + this.username + "/path";
    },
});
```

To use this after instanciation, you could set the `username` field of your collection manually or you could override the [`sync`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-171) method of your collection.

```
var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: function() {
        return "base-url/" + this.username + "/path";
    },

    sync: function(method, model, options) {
        options = options || {};
        if (options.username) this.username = options.username;

        // call the default sync
        return Backbone.collection.prototype.sync.call(this, method, model, options);
    }
});
```

And use it:

```
myCollection.fetch({ username: "Mac" });
```

**Additional information on how to know how url is called**

I'm an avid user of the [annotated source](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html) of Backbone and it's really important as a lot of Backbone's features are undocumented and the sources are small and easy to go through.

If you check the [`sync`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-171) method, you should see that line:

```
params.url = _.result(model, 'url') || urlError();
```

And if you check the underscore's [`result`](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-163) function, you can see that it calls the function (passed as a string) like this:

```
return _.isFunction(value) ? value.call(object) : value;
```